# Lie algebra associated to an arbitrary discrete group

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, lie-algebras

I read somewhere that there is a classical (due to Philip Hall?) construction of a Lie algebra associated to any discrete group $\pi$ which is obtained from filtration quotients of the descending central series of $\pi$. Can anyone recommend some introductory material on this construction?

Comment: Yes, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94860/lie-algebra-for-a-general-group for references. For nilpotent discrete groups $\Gamma$ in a Lie group $G$ there is also the Malcev completion $G_{\Gamma}$ with Lie algebra $\frak{g}_{\Gamma}$.

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde! By the way, is this kind of question more suitable for mathoverflow or math.stackexchange?

Comment: I think that this sort of question is better for MSE, because at MO they really want research questions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I reread the answers and I believe that the one given by Ralph is exactly what I am looking for. But he only gave the definition without mentioning specific references. Do you happen to know some materials on this subject?

Comment: Since the work of Zelmanov this is explained in many books and articles, e.g., in the book "New Horizons in pro-p Groups" by Marcus du Sautoy, Dan Segal and Aner Shalev. But you have asked Ralph already, I saw.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, yes, I have asked Ralph but have not received any reply yet. Thank you for recommending the book! Did you mean that the construction was attributed to Zelmanov?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in Lazard's thesis (which may even have been mentioned in the linked MO question?)

Sur les groupes nilpotents et les anneaux de Lie:
http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1954_3_71_2/ASENS_1954_3_71_2_101_0/ASENS_1954_3_71_2_101_0.pdf

Specifically Theorem 2.1 and Corollary 6.8. But the whole paper is basically about this, so all sorts of "relevant facts" are included.

Also relevant is Quillen's paper "On the associated graded ring of a group ring" which proves that the associated graded ring of the group algebra of a p-group in characteristic p (with respect to its augmentation ideal) is the same as the universal enveloping algebra of the associated restricted Lie algebra.

Comment: Thanks Dylan! This goes to show how carefully I read the answers to that question... Now, those results you quote are about "N-suites (restreintes)", so I guess I also want to know that the specific sequences of subgroups I wrote are "N-suites (restrientes)". For the non-restricted case this is in the last sentence of the paragraph after Theorem 2.1. Let me see if can find the result that the $H_i$ I wrote form an "N-suite restreinte".

Comment: Also, Lazard in the introduction mentions that the Lie algebra associated to the lower central series and to the "mod p dimension groups" were previously defined by Magnus and Zassenhaus respectively. So maybe for the lower central series Magnus is the original source of the claim I want. I bet that for the restricted Lie algebra associated to the mod p lower central series this paper of Lazard's might be the original source (and Zassenhaus might be the source for the underlying Lie algebra of said restricted Lie algebra).

Comment: Argh. The $G_{i,p}$ in Lazard's thesis seem not be the same as what I called the mod p lower central series (sometimes also called the [lower exponent-p central series](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Lower_exponent-p_central_series)), but rather they are the same as both Zassenhaus's mod p dimension groups and as the [Jennings series](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Jennings_series). I don't think the lower exponent p central series is one of Lazard's restricted N-sequences.

Comment: Confusion may not be my totally fault: both of those series are sometimes called the mod p lower central series!

Comment: :( oh man, the terminology here is confusing. On an unrelated note, Quillen calls those "restricted N-sequences" just "p-filtrations", which seems better terminology by far. Also thanks for pointing out the correct history!