# Can any one recommend a way to "quickly" learn a subject?

Tags: self-learning, lie-algebras, learning

I would love to read a well written book on a subject - provided that I have the time. But sometimes we do not need to become experts on a particular field but still need the basics. For example, a question in my research is related to Lie algebra, which I know very little about, thus I would like to learn the basics of Lie algebra. However, I do not have say $300$ hours to read a text book such as GTM $9$ (Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory, James E. Humphreys) in detail.

Let's say that I can spend $30$ hours on this subject and would like to learn the basics, can anyone recommend some materials/methods? Currently I am watching a [youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gttJICxC3s&list=PL280D5EC5C78AF009) 
on Lie algebras and their representations but I am not sure if it is the best way to "quickly" learn the basics of the subject.

Comment: "Learn about Lie algebras" is extremely broad. The more specific you can be about what you actually need to know, the more focused you can be about what you read. So what do you actually need to know?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thanks for the comment. I am mainly interested in the graded Lie algebra associated to an arbitrary group. More specifically, I need to compute the graded Lie algebra structure of some specific groups, using the commutative diagram of split exact sequences of Lie algebras.

Comment: Okay, that's very specific. A typical book on Lie algebras won't tell you anything about that (although it'll be worth reading anyway). Mostly they're about Lie algebras associated to Lie groups. It sounds like you should look at books on group theory that cover that construction instead.

Comment: Thanks @QiaochuYuan, any particular reference you would recommend?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about this subject unfortunately.

Comment: No problem at all. Thank you again for your comment and valuable information!

Comment: More information is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000057/lie-algebra-associated-to-an-arbitrary-discrete-group#comment2075113_1000057).